# React Bootstrap Modal closes when I click anywhere inside the modal

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap version 1.5.2 in react version 17.0.1. The problem is that the modal closes immediately after I click anywhere inside the modal body and that is not its natural behavior. I looked at some other questions that suggested using backdrop={ 'static' } but that too didn't work.

The other modal that I have in the page opens just fine and that too has the same components - the accordion inside. The only thing that is different here is I have get methods in useState and elements inside accordion is editable (used some functions there) but I dont think they are related to this modal behaviour as I haven't used anything to trigger the state. This the code how I have implemented the modal.

```
    //the show.hide toggle is the usestate
    const [showHelper, setShowHelper] = useState(false);


   <div className="clarify-icon" onClick={() => setShowHelper(true)}>
    <FaInfoCircle size="24" color="#BC2A20" className="pointer" />
  </div>
  <Modal
    show={showHelper}
    // backdrop="static"
    onHide={() => setShowHelper(false)}
    className="modal-left"
  >
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>Helper Text Templates</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
    ...
  </Modal>
```

It is pretty much the same thing. I am not sure what went wrong here.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of your code in something like codeSanbox?

Comment: possible please provide the codesandbox

Comment: provide sample full functional code, with the code you provided doesn't seems like a problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aaippq?file=src/App.js

Comment: Even I created not able to reproduce this issue - https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bouman-mboel?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You should see carefully if you have any click event registered with some element inside of model contents if yes then see if that click results to call some props method,
In that case click will be causing parent's re-render and default state will be causing this issue.
If its so you should manage show/hide state in parent component